# Chartjs and chart-data Angular

Tags: angularjs, charts, angular-chart

Is there a way to add chart data from ng-repeat.

like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in chartData">
<canvas style="padding:5px" tc-chartjs-pie chart-options="chartOptions" chart-data="{{key}}">
</div>
```

I am trying to add multiple charts to the page and I am using dynamic data from the controller. I cant seem to find any reference in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to output data from the controller assuming your controller has something like this:

```
$scope.chartData[yourDynamicVar] = [
          .... chart data
        ]
```

**you can do this:**

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in chartData">
        <canvas tc-chartjs-pie chart-options="chartOptions"chart-data="chartData[key]"></canvas>
</div>
```